# Three horizontal line icon and filter result icons in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add 3 horizontal line icons inside the green box and the icon shows the right side in the search bar. here's my code for the green box and search bar. I want to add those icons to this code. you can refer to the picture to get an idea about the icons I want to add to my code.

[image]

```
 body: ListView(


        children: [

                  Row(
                    children: [

                      Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 50, 0, 0),
                          child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          color: Color(0xffCAEC93),
                        ),

                        height: 60,
                        width: 60,

                           child: Column(
                             children: [
                          IconButton(
                           icon: new Icon(
                             Icons.more_horiz_outlined, // where I want to add 3 horizontal line icon
                             color: Colors.white,
                           ), onPressed: () {
                            onPressed: () {Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>  HomePage()));
                            };
                          },
                          ),
                             ],


                        ),
                      )

                      ),

                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,  45, 0, 0),
                          child: buildSearchInput(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],

                  ),

),
```

//search bar widget

```
Widget buildSearchInput() => Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 0, 20, 0),
    child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  size: 30,
                  color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                ),
                // Padding(
                //   padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 0, 5, 0),
                //   child: Icon(
                //     Icons.search,
                //     size: 30,
                //     color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                //
                //   ),
                // ),
                Flexible(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
```

Comment: Please add expected output photo also

Comment: the photo I have already uploaded is the expected output.  I have just designed the green box and search bar without icons as you see in the code.

Answer (score 2):

For Menu icon you can use this

```
Icon(
                        Icons.menu,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 25.sp,
                      )
```

unfortunately flutter not have filter icon. You have to download that icon as png and use in `Image.asset`

Comment: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/sliders.png",), <<< I have add image like this. but it display unable to load

Comment: Have you added assets in pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: yes I have add it

Comment: make sure you have restart your app.